# How to select the value of a specific resource in tuple based on a property value?

Tags: terraform

Hello im struggling a little to solve this challenge and hope someone can provide insights. I need to pick a specific resource out of a tuple of those resources based on a property on that resource. How would one go about achieving something like that?

Code looks something like:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "network_interface" {
    for_each = var.counter_of_2
    // stuff
}

resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "currently_used_eni" {
    instance_id = var.instance_id
    network_interface_id = <the aws_network_interface with tag.Name = "thisone">
    device_index = 0
}
```

Comment: You could maybe do that by using the data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/network_interface.

Comment: Hmm I thought about that as well, but I wasn't quite sure about how to actually achieve it. Maybe something like:
Create a Data source based on that aws_network_interface tuple --> Through that Data source access the properties of each element.

Comment: There is an easier way though if the variable used in `for_each` can be mapped in a different way to the attachment. For example, if you would use names in `counter_of_2` variable which correspond to the `Name` tag you could easily connect the two.

Answer (score 0):

Because `tag` is not ID of resource something like that would be impossible. Imagine if you have two network interfaces with same tag. Which one should it take?

But your case might be not lost. (yet it might... depends on case)

I assume that if you want to find specific `aws_network_interface` then tags are unique. And if they are unique then every network interface have different tag. So you can simply use something like that:

```
aws_network_interface.network_interface["value_from_for_each"]
```

For simplicity (and assuming that one network interface = one tag) I'll make this `for_each` collection to be set of tag names.

```
variable "interface_tags" {
    type = set(string)
    default = ["tag1", "tag2", "thisone"]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "network_interface" {
    for_each = var.interface_tags
    // stuff
}

resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "currently_used_eni" {
    instance_id = var.instance_id
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.network_interface["thisone"].id
    device_index = 0
}
```

And this should work (and I hope it can be used in your case)